# Вставка переменной в файл js

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток всем. Во время розроботки сайта на node js мне понадобилось сделать: у меня в правой части страници есть 2 менюшки. Одно из них(логин меню) должна выводиться если пользователь не залогинен, вторая если залогинен. Вытащил все это с ejs и засунул в js(с проверкой) .

```
module.exports.rightSide = function (req,res,next) {
sess = req.session;
if(sess.email==undefined) {
    menu =
        '<div id="login_form">' +
        '<div id="login_form_title">' + '<h2>' + '<span class="lang" key="login">' + 'увійти до системи' + '</span>' + '</h2>' + '</div>' +
        '<p>'+'</p>'+
        '<form id="login" action="/login" method="POST">' +
        '<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="username" required="true">' + '<br>' + '<br>' +
        '<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">' + '<br>' + '<br>' +
        '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="lgs">' +
        '</form>' +
        '<div id="ger_forg">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">' +
        '<div id="registration">' + '<a href="#openModal">' + '<span class="lang" key="registration">' + 'реєстрація' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' +
        <!-- Registration form-->
        '<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">' +
        '<div>' +
        '<a href="#close" title="Закрити" class="close">' + 'X' + '</a>' +
        '<h3 class="lang" key="type-text">' + 'Заповніть усі поля:' + '</h3>' +
        '<p style="color: red">' + req.session.em + '</p>'+
        '<form action="/registration" method="POST" id="regForm" autocomplete="on">' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="last-name">' + 'Прізвище' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="text" name="lastName" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="name">' + 'Ім\'я' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="text" name="name" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="telephone">' + 'Телефон' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="tel" name="tel" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="e-mail">' + 'Електронна пошта' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="email" name="mail" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="login">' + 'Логін' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="text" name="login" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="password">' + 'Пароль' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="13" required>' + '</p>' +
        '<p>' + '<span class="lang" key="repeat-password">' + 'Повторіть пароль' + '</span>' +
        '<br>' + '<input type="password" name="repeatPassword" maxlength="13" required>' + '</p>' +
        <!-- Re-captcha -->
        '<input type="submit" id="send" value="Надіслати" name="submit">' +
        '</form>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        <!-- End of registration form-->
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">' +
        '<div id="forgot_password">' + '<a href="">' + '<span class="lang" key="forgotPassword">' + 'забули пароль' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
}else {
    menu = '<div id="question">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">' +
        '<div id="employee_name">' + '<h2>' + '<a href="">' + sess.fName +' '+ sess.lName + '</a>' + '</h2>' + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">' +
        '<div id="gear_ico">' + '<img src="images/gear_ico.png" alt="">' + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<ul id="question_menu">' +
        '<li id="status_waiting">' + '<a href="">' + 'Питання з дуже-дуже довже...' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
        '<li id="status_done">' + '<a href="">' + 'Якесь виконане питання' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
        '<li id="status_denied">' + '<a href="">' + 'Питання, що відхилено' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<ul id="add_question">' +
        '<li id="plus">' + '<a href="">' + '<span class="lang" key="addQuestion">' + 'Додати питання' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">' +
        '<div id="all_questions">' + '<a href="">' + '<span class="lang" key="allQuestions">' + 'усі питання(12)' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">' +
        '<div id="exit">' + '<a href="/logout">' + '<span class="lang" key="exit">' + 'вийти' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    }
return menu;
```

};

Вот так стал выглядеть файл ejs

```
<aside>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <%- menu %>
</div>
```

А теперь суть проблемы: мне нужно в файл js втсавить такую же переменну. как в ejs типу <%- menu %> описаную в роутере

```
router.get('/', function( req, res, next) {
//var errorr = erR.er(req,res,next);
var men = menu.rightSide(req,res,next);
sess = req.session;
    res.render
    (
        'index',
        {
            title: 'site a3boot',
            news_text: text,
            menu : men
        }
    );
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я неверно понял ваш вопрос, поправьте, если это так.

Вы генерируете меню, вызывая функцию

```
var men = menu.rightSide(req,res,next);
```

Представленный вами .js файл, содержащий код меню, начинается с

```
module.exports.rightSide = function (req,res,next) {
```

Добавьте к аргументам функции еще один, options, к примеру:

```
module.exports.rightSide = function (req,res,next, options) {
```

и при вызове функции передавайте туда все, что вам потребуется:

```
var men = menu.rightSide(req,res,next,{foo:bar});
```

Comment: А как мне это потом вывести на страницу? если же просто написать foo видает undefined, а методом как в ejs не работает.

Comment: Вы же в объекте options передаете значения. Из него и берите: options.foo